# Slip-Condition for Fluid between Parallel Plates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, stress-strain

When we have two parallel plates separated by distance $h$, the plate at the top moves with velocity $V$, while the one at the bottom remains stationary, and we consider that the fluid flow between two parallel plates has a slip of,
$$ \delta u \approx \ell \frac{du}{dy}$$

This is my initial approach, which could very well be incorrect:

I considered, $du/dy = V/h$ so $\delta u \approx \ell V/h $ and for the shear stress $\tau  = \mu \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$

For $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{U_{top}-U_{bottom}}{h}$$

Where I considered the fluid's velocity at the top plate to be,  $U_{top} = V - \delta u$ , and at the bottom, $U_{bot} = 0 + \delta u$.

In order to improve my understanding, I searched for a diagram that illustrated the phenomena, which shows (apologies for the low quality) :

[image: Diagram for slip]

This $b$ distance is the $\ell$ of my equation at the top. So I am wondering if it should be included as part of the $dy$ term, as $dy = h - \ell$  or should it be part of $\partial y  = h - \ell $. Or perhaps my original analysis was correct? Let me know where I am going wrong.
I am not unsure how to describe this system mathematically.

Thanks a lot, your time and help are very appreciated.

Comment: It's far from clear what your actual question is?

Comment: The question is in the last paragraph. "Should I include b, as part of my dy term, such that $ dy  = h - b $, or as $\partial y = h - b$ or is the way I analyzed initially correct (where $dy = \partial y$ as can be seen above)? " It all depends on what is the proper way to analyze this system, but I did not want to ask for the solution.